# I am not understanding the raw_input

Tags: python, while-loop

```
loop_flag = 1
 while loop_flag == 1:
    choice = raw_input("Enter 'quit' to Exit the loop: ")
    if choice == 'quit':
     loop_flag = 1
    else:
       print ("Keep Going")
```

---

I am having problems with this raw_input
The message is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Exemm\Downloads\TNCC\ITN_260_Network_security_basics\Week 6                                 02.13 – 02.19\Lab 1 - Copy (4)\ts.py", line 4, in <module>
    choice = raw_input ("Enter 'quit' to Exit the loop: ")
  *NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined**
```

Comment: Tag the question with the appropriate language tag. Is this python? If so, the indentation looks incorrect. Also, shouldn't `If` be `if`, `=  “quit”` be `==  "quit"`, and `“` be `"` ?

Comment: I tried to indent here, but I did not manage to do. I will try again. I don't understand your last comment " be ". Sorry, I am learning.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. It seems you are not using the correct quote character.

Comment: The quotation marks in your code are not the standard ASCII quotation mark characters (ASCII code 34).

Comment: `“Foo“` is bad, `"Foo"` is good. `If` is bad, `if` is good.

Comment: Ok. I got it about quotation.

Comment: Did you really read the error? It says `name 'raw_input' is not defined`. So it's not an error with the loop, but with `raw_input`. I think you run your program with Python 3 where `raw_input` is now called `input` while the `input` from Python 2 is completely gone.

Comment: When I tried for the first time, it appears the error while and of course, with this advices, I fix it, but after that, the second error appears - raw_input. I will test your advice to see if I can correct.

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you all for this lesson. Thank Matthias, Michael, Valens for the patience. I am learning a lot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loop_flag = 1
while loop_flag == 1:
    choice = raw_input("Enter ‘quit’ to Exit the Loop: ")
    if choice == "quit":
        loop_flag = 0
    else:
        print "Keep Going"
```

Comment: I suppose that the author is getting "IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Comment: The message is that I didn't define the raw_input

Comment: Instead of just providing code, can you explain your answer a bit?  How is the POST's code wrong?

Comment: Yes. I did provide the raw_input but when I run - it appears this *NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined**, then I don't know  what is my mistake. Sorry, but I am learning Python recently and it is difficult to understand the whole picture.

Comment: raw_input is not defined? u may run it in python 3? use input() instead.

Comment: Yes. Now it is working. Thank you. I understood the process.

Comment: @Michael has explained errors in POST's code except the wrong cycle flag. i thought the poster may wants an example.

Comment: @valens - I would like to finish the cycle.